# Python 3.9 - strongly typed callbacks with known first argument type and additional args typed in the function definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of a few dozen simple callbacks with various arguments, defined as such:

```
def test_value(tested: Tested, value: int) -> bool:
  return tested.value >= value

def test_value_and_name(tested: Tested, value: int, name: str) -> bool:
  return tested.value >= value and tested.name === name

def test_owned_thing(tested: Tested, thing: Thing)
  return tested.thing === thing
```

As you can see, all of them are functions supposed to be called on a `Tested` object.

---

There is a global "tester" function that is supposed to test all `Tested` objects that exist. But I'm struggling with how to type it in a way that provides correct type hints for all of the predicates.

```
def tester_all(predicate: Callable[???????, bool], *args: ???, **kwargs: ???) -> bool:
  return all(predicate(tested, ????) for tested in GLOBAL_TESTED_LIST)
```

This is the kind of type hints that I expect:

```
tester_all(test_value, 5)                // correct
tester_all(test_value, value=5)          // correct
tester_all(test_value)                   // type error: missing argument
tester_all(test_value, 'string value')   // type error: argument should be int
tester_all(test_value, 5, 2137682)       // type error: too many arguments

tester_all(test_value_and_name, 5, 'some name') // correct
tester_all(test_value_and_name, 5)              // type error: not enough arguments
tester_all(test_value_and_name, 5, 5)           // type error: second argument must be a string
tester_all(test_value_and_name, 'some name', 5) // type error: int should be first and string second, not other way around

tester_all(test_owned_thing, Thing())  // correct
tester_all(test_owned_thing, 5)        // type error: int is not a Thing
```

I tried many various solutions sprinkled all over SO, including those using `Protocol`s, but I can't find how to make any of them work exactly as I want it to.

From what I gathered so far, it seems I either have to completely lose callback argument typing (and even counting!), or lose the ability to write any number of new typed predicates without having to also update some externally defined Callable/Protocol typings list for my tester.

Which seems weird to me. I just want to define functions and use them as callbacks with typed arguments. Is that too much to ask? ; ) Perhaps my approach is wrong here and it could be made simpler?

(For additional context, I'm the owner of the codebase and I'm happy to introduce additional (preferably simple) type helpers, but my Python version is hard-capped at 3.9 because of an external technical requirement that I can't affect.)

Comment: You need to fix your syntax - did you copy something straight from TypeScript?

Comment: I didn't. Care to elaborate what's wrong with it other than `//` instead of `#` for comments?

Comment: `===` is not valid in Python either

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Of course I'm new to Python and I come from TS background. I copied my Python code and then altered it in SO plaintext editor (so now it's probably at a point where it can be considered more of a pseudo-code) because my question wasn't meant to be about fixing my syntax anyway. I have my IDE for that. : )

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [PEP 612 - Parameter Specification Variables](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/). Although this is only available in the standard library in Python 3.10, you can use it in earlier versions by importing from [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) instead of the standard library's `typing`. I don't know what type checker you're using, but some checkers such as mypy already have it as a dependency, so you don't need to install it separately.

Here's a mockup of your example with full static type annotations:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    P = t.ParamSpec("P")

GLOBAL_TESTED_LIST: t.Final[list[Tested]] = []

class Tested:
    value: int
    name: str
    thing: Thing

class Thing: ...

def test_value(tested: Tested, value: int) -> bool:
    return tested.value >= value

def test_value_and_name(tested: Tested, value: int, name: str) -> bool:
    return tested.value >= value and tested.name == name

def test_owned_thing(tested: Tested, thing: Thing) -> bool:
    return tested.thing == thing

def tester_all(
    predicate: cx.Callable[t.Concatenate[Tested, P], bool],
    *args: P.args,
    **kwargs: P.kwargs,
) -> bool:
    return all(predicate(tested, *args, **kwargs) for tested in GLOBAL_TESTED_LIST)
```

`tester_all` is annotated to

- Expect a `predicate` which is a callable taking one [positional-only](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) object of type `Tested`, trailed by any kinds of arguments (positional or keyword) represented by the single type `P`;
- Expect the same kinds of positional arguments followed by keyword arguments as the trailing arguments of `predicate`, represented by `*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs`.

The static typing errors are as follows (live examples shown on [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=8047cc6ba5bc7ce53e9d971736e6632e), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?pyrightVersion=1.1.337&pythonVersion=3.9&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChGd9CokBPXLUgcxhoAHkjQNaDEvQ7MswDgDoAKgE0ACgFEYAYQASG7QGkAkgDkA4gC5GUW9jwEiAYzAAbV2ic069BcQBGTlJQTkI2dmpQALyKasQgxBAAyrieABQARGoZAJTM5gAyAPIAQgCCBTBKGknVACIwBca1looAYrzErgDarlj0SN1KaANoACYAuhPRUN0TzE6uxPTSw6Nj1nZQAG5dCGitvEjhtqSJB1ADICccABa8fK1K9-wLSytQzw%2BtCr-MY2h5KIBjBdq59mlgaINp8RtCADQ7PYXI45KAAWgAfFB-GA3Js7OgUCBSBw4eMFGD9lBMTEqWh-oCySD6TAyGMYGcIGhIeSYWsEUjwSjSEhEVyLlc0VicXjXATbETUKSoRT6TS6ciSKQxszoQoJdEYhLGUC4TAwAB3UjjGBIF58XnrJ58xH276fB3S7G4-E3JUkvUU938I13B6moMgNnuNI3XDoMZYJzUC6hBTaLpLfwebpIDN0FOiM6iIauqBqCaI32uKs3ABU8T49Faaj8IGb8Ib9YA1pamy2Kwo%2BwOu97ZX6tgHSVm0gnxsnU07BY2O-REfXe-212jgAQg7reFBCqUKlUavVGs0lHlmKro7OoaDkYiAKx5e8x1zL5-CxH0qJ30YT9H3NekP3JB9YyfelEQyK4HiFfZcmAyCvx-WCoFfREACYAEYAGYAHYADYAA4cNvEDoLA5E2R1TlzjfOD6EgNAoAlFDqO-GC6PZRjuTfCDRignjaOFeiOQlZisOE0RRIwviGOkqB4LYjjzgyIS7zQ0CQStG0ORDPhES%2Bfg0hyOS0AUp8DNtYztKAA)):

```
>>> tester_all(test_value, 5)
>>> tester_all(test_value, value=5)
>>> tester_all(test_value)                           # mypy: Missing positional argument "value" in call to "tester_all" [call-arg]
>>> tester_all(test_value, "string value")           # mypy: Argument 2 to "tester_all" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" [arg-type]
>>> tester_all(test_value, 5, 2137682)               # mypy: Too many arguments for "tester_all" [call-arg]
>>> 
>>> tester_all(test_value_and_name, 5, "some name")
>>> tester_all(test_value_and_name, 5)               # mypy: Missing positional argument "name" in call to "tester_all" [call-arg]
>>> tester_all(test_value_and_name, 5, 5)            # mypy: Argument 3 to "tester_all" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str" [arg-type]
>>> tester_all(test_value_and_name, "some name", 5)  # mypy: Argument 2 to "tester_all" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" [arg-type] \
...                                                  # mypy: Argument 3 to "tester_all" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str" [arg-type]
>>> 
>>> tester_all(test_owned_thing, Thing())
>>> tester_all(test_owned_thing, 5)                  # mypy: Argument 2 to "tester_all" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Thing" [arg-type]
```

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, it looks your tester_all function wants to take a Union of Callable types: something like:

```
def tester_all(predicate: Union[Callable[[Tested, int], bool], Callable[[Tested, int, str], bool], Callable[[Tested, Thing], bool]],...)
```

However, that's not going to ensure that the right arguments are passed along with the right callable type. I don't know of a way to do that.

Seems like you *could* pre-bind the arguments to each. Define `tester_all` as taking just a `Callable` argument with a single `Tested` argument, then pass the additional arguments bound via lambda to it as:

```
def tester_all(predicate: Callable[[Tested], bool]) -> bool:
    return all(predicate(tested) for tested in GLOBAL_TESTED_LIST)

tester_all(lambda tested: test_value(tested, 5))
tester_all(lambda tested: test_value(tested, value=5))
tester_all(lambda tested: test_value(tested))
...
```

That would allow type-checking to be done outside of the call to `tester_all` for the lambdas (assuming the type-checker is smart enough to grok what's going on), and still allow `tester_all` to be properly typed as well.

Comment: Oh yeah, the functional way! I came up with this a few hours after posting the question, and tbh, I believe this might be the best answer to my problem. It might make the predicates more reusable for users outside of `Tester`, which aren't necessarily supposed to know about and import the `Tested` class. For now this approach seems to be working and doing what I wanted, so when later today I make 100% sure it's fine, I'll come back here to confirm.